# How subtract a value of a total using checkboxes?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to subtract a value of a total using checkboxes.
Let's say I have values in Column A (10,20,56) and A4 is the total, on column B I have checkboxes for each row. Now, when I click on the checkbox next to the value 10, I will like to subtract that value from the total on A4(86), so the result will get 76. Subsequently, if I click on the checkbox next to 20, then the value of the total (A4) will change to 56.

[image: Google Sheet Picture]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Your problem description does not match the screenshot. The answer below follows the description and not the screenshot. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169359/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` to get the rows where the checkbox is *not* ticked, and sum those rows, like this:

```
=sum(filter(A1:A4, not(B1:B4)))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: Thank you, this definately has helped.